# Deference of a pointer to a structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to figure out, which meaning does the deference of a pointer to a structure has:

```
struct example{
int x;
}

struct example a = {20};
struct example *b = &a;
```

Now my problem:

`&a` is the address of the struct

`&b` is the address of the pointer to the struct

b will be the address of the struct on which the struct pointer b is referenced

Now:

```
(*b).x = 21;
```

(*b): if that is deferencing the pointer to the address of the struct, which is the difference between `(*b)` and `b`?

I have tryed to print out if the two addresses are the same:

```
printf("%p, %p", *b, b);
```

And the answer is not! Could someone explain where am I wrong?

Comment: `delete b;` should be for you

Comment: `struct a = ` is a syntax error, so is `struct b* = ...`. **Post actual code.**

Comment: Do you meen free from C? ... Because in C delete() does not exist.

Comment: @Victor `delete`? In C? By the way, here there's absolutely no dynamic allocation going on, so even `free()` is not to be used.

Comment: Tnx H2CO3, I have updated the post... "struct example a =" is what I relly wanted to say

Comment: There are still multiple syntax errors in the code.

Comment: @ interjay: yeap now solved. Btw. *b in printf was intended. That's part of my question

Comment: @Blue Moon... Yes, there is something I don't understand. This is the reason, why I posted the question :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `printf("%p, %p", *b, b);`, the argument `*b` is a struct. The behavior of printing a struct with a `%p` specifier is not defined by the C standard. Whatever value you saw printed is effectively garbage; it has no meaning.

The ways that C implementations may respond when you use `printf` in this way **include**, but are not limited to:

- The struct `*b` is passed as an argument (by placing the bytes that represent it in registers or memory designated for the third argument of a call), then `printf` reinterprets those bytes (which contain an `int`) as if they were a pointer and prints the value of that pointer. `printf` then goes on to print the `b` argument.
- The struct `*b` is passed as above, and `printf` prints it, but, because the size of the argument (a struct) differs from what `printf` expects (a pointer), the location of the next argument is calculated incorrectly, so `printf` uses the wrong bytes for it and does not print the `b` argument correctly.
- Passing incorrect arguments results in stack corruption, and the program crashes.

Also note that, when the `%p` specifier is used, any pointers that are passed should be cast to `void *` (or `const void *`). Passing any other kind of pointer for `%p` is also undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In your arguments to `printf`, `b` is a pointer, and `*b` is a `struct example`, not a pointer.  `printf` is displaying `b` correctly because it is a memory address, but it is <strike>casting</strike> converting `*b` (ie: your struct) to a pointer, this is why the two numbers are different.

Edit: I've updated 'casting' to 'converting' in response to Eric Postpischil's comment.  Terminology aside, the rest of the answer is correct, and here's proof:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   struct test {
      int x;
   };

   struct test t;
   t.x = 0xdeadbeef;

   printf( "%p\n", &t );
   printf( "%p\n", t );

   return 0;
}
```

The output of this is:

```
0x7fff5b674b98
0xdeadbeef
```

Note the compiler should be warning you of this:

```
test.c:13:20: warning: format specifies type 'void *' but the argument has type
  'struct test' [-Wformat]
```

... but that's besides the point; that's the answer to your question ;)

Comment: This answer is incorrect. First, there is no cast, because a cast is an explicit “(*type*)” in the source code. You probably meant that `*b` is **converted** to a pointer, not **cast**. Second, there is no conversion. `*b` is not converted at all; it is the struct `a`, not its address, and it is the struct `a` that is passed to `printf`, not its address. The behavior of printing a struct with a `%p` specifier is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: Indeed! I have figured out: `*p` is actually a symbol for a structure as `a`. What I was intended to do is this: `printf("%p, %p", &(*b), b)`. `&(*b)` and `b` should now be equivalent!

Comment: @AsamRegnat: `printf("%p, %p", &(*b), b)` happens to work in many C implementations, but, technically, you should use `printf("%p, %p", (void *) &(*b), (void *) b);`. In some now-rare C implementations, pointers of different types are different sizes, and it is necessary to cast them to `void *` to get a common type to use with `%p`.